# If loop that executes when Enter key is pressed C++

Tags: c++

I'm using Windows XP Home Edition.  I want to set up a menu system that displays an image when the Enter key is pressed.  Is there any way I can set up an if statement that executes when the Enter key is pressed on the keyboard without setting up a GUI.  For example, can I just use the hex value associated with Enter key as a trigger for the if statement.

I've looked into reading input buffers.  Am I going to have to get that complex with it?  I don't really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For windows there are a couple of variants you could use to implement this:

1. The standard way would be to call e.g. [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and discard the input.
2. A more Windows-specific solution is to use e.g. [`_kbhit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58w7c94c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [`_getch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to check for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.